# the entire time / that / for which

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> Have you totally blocked out the entire time we were a couple?

Can I rewrite this sentence above as shown below:

> 1- Have you totally blocked out ***for*** the entire time we were a couple?
>
> 2- Have you totally blocked out the entire time ***that*** we were a couple?
>
> 3- Have you totally blocked out the ***for*** entire time ***that*** we were a
>   couple?
>
> 4- Have you totally blocked out the entire time ***for*** ***which*** we were a
>   couple?
>
> 5-  Have you totally blocked out ***for*** the entire time ***for*** ***which*** we were a
>   couple? (Is this version grammatically wrong? or does it just sound
>   very weird? )

Comment: What do you think Talha? And why do you ask? Is this a test that you were given or have you composed the questions yourself?

Comment: I am just wondering. It is not a test, I made up all these versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Have you totally blocked out for the entire time we were a couple?

No.

> 2- Have you totally blocked out the entire time that we were a couple?

Yes, sounds fine.

> 3- Have you totally blocked out the for entire time that we were a couple?

No.

> 4- Have you totally blocked out the entire time for which we were a couple?

No.  You could replace "for which" with "during which" and it would be correct but would sound overly formal for this context.

> 5- Have you totally blocked out for the entire time for which we were a couple? (Is this version grammatically wrong? or does it just sound very weird? )

No, it's grammatically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking a former partner whether **s/he has forgotten the whole time you were together**.

If this is really what you intend, example 2 is grammatically correct and clearly stated.

Example 4 is clear but clumsy. It's not idiomatic.

Examples 1, 3 & 5, which include the preposition **for** are all ungrammatical.

In Example 3 you have reversed the words **the** and **for**.

The preposition **for** doesn't belong unless you intend to ask a different question.

Do you want to know whether someone has blocked out **an entire period of time** (Example 2) or **something for a period of time**.

To add to these difficulties, the expression **blocked out** can be ambiguous. It can be used in the senses of **forget, ignore, or forcing oneself not to think about**.

In short, your question might be better phrased to make your meaning crystal clear.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/block%20out